# Customize linetype in ggplot2 OR add automatic arrows/symbols below a line

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

**I would like to use customized linetypes in ggplot. If that is impossible (which I believe to be true), then I am looking for a smart hack to plot arrowlike symbols above, or below, my line.**

Some background:
I want to plot some water quality data and compare it to the standard (set by the European Water Framework Directive) in a red line. Here's some reproducible data and my plot:

```
df <- data.frame(datum <- seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"),
      as.Date("2014-12-31"),by = "week"),y=rnorm(53,mean=100,sd=40))

(plot1 <- 
ggplot(df, aes(x=datum,y=y)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic()+ 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=70),colour="red"))
```

However, in this plot it is completely unclear if the Standard is a maximum value (as it would be for example Chloride) or a minimum value (as it would be for Oxygen). So I would like to make this clear by adding small pointers/arrows Up or Down. The best way would be to customize the linetype so that it consists of these arrows, but I couldn't find a way.
 **Q1: Is this at all possible, defining custom linetypes?**

All I could think of was adding extra points below the line:

```
extrapoints <- data.frame(datum2 <- seq.Date(as.Date("2014-01-01"),
    as.Date("2014-12-31"),by = "week"),y2=68)

plot1 + geom_point(data=extrapoints, aes(x=datum2,y=y2),
        shape=">",size=5,colour="red",rotate=90)
```

[image: plot1]

However, I can't seem to rotate these symbols pointing downward. Furthermore, this requires calculating the right spacing of X and distance to the line (Y) every time, which is rather inconvenient. 
**Q2: Is there any way to achieve this, preferably as automated as possible?**

Comment: What do you mean with the right spacing of x? If I'm honest, even with rotating the arrows (`plot1 + geom_text(data=extrapoints, aes(x=datum2,y=y2, label=">"),angle=90, color="red")`) it doesn't really make things clear. How about creating coloured rectangles to indicate within/outside acceptable range?

Comment: @Heroka I think a line consisting of downward pointing arrows makes clear the value should be below that line. The thought of coloured rectangles e.g. with `geom_ribbon` crossed my mind too and might solve this problem. But I was also curious if custom linetypes were possible and if not, how others would approach this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what is requested, but it sounds as though you want arrows at point up or down based on where the y-value is greater or less than some expected value. If that's the case, then this satisfies using `geom_segment`:

```
 require(grid) # as noted by ?geom_segment
 (plot1 <- 
ggplot(df, aes(x=datum,y=y)) + geom_line()+
  geom_segment(data = data.frame( df$datum, y= 70, up=df$y >70), 
             aes(xend = datum , yend =70 + c(-1,1)[1+up]*5), #select up/down based on 'up'
                arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1,"cm"))
              ) +                            # adjust units to modify size or arrow-heads
  geom_point() +
  theme_classic()+ 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=70),colour="red"))
```

[image]

If I'm wrong about what was desired and you only wanted a bunch of down arrows, then just take out the stuff about creating and using "up" and use a minus-sign.

Comment: I would prefer a custom linetype, but this is a very nice alternative. Clever use of `geom_segment`. Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid "custom linetype" is not sufficiently descriptive or directive to drive my imagination.

Comment: Standard linetypes are solid, dashed, dotted etc. I wondered if it is possible to define own linetypes, for example consisting af a symbol. Say a line of aaaaaaaaaaaa or ###########.

Comment: Why not use geom_text with  the "label" argument of your choice? The base and lattice plotting functions allow the use of a `pch` argument.  I did a simple search on ggplot2 and pch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4377031/using-pch-characters-in-grid-text

Comment: Thanks, that looks very interesting!